# Postgresql, getting the most recent entries from table based on unique field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the following to return a list of the most recent unique records based on the "server"

```
select server, fail, date, time
from (
    select server, fail, date, time,
           rank() over (partition by server order by date desc, time desc) as rank
    from querytimes
) dt
where dt.rank <= 1;
```

It works, however its pretty slow.

Time: 21470.742 ms

Output example,

```
  server       | fail |    date    |   time
-------------------+------+------------+----------
serv1.test.com  | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:03
serv2.test.com  | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:03
serv3.test.com  | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:03
serv4.test.com  | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:03
serv5.test.com  | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:03
serv6.test.com  | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:03
serv7.test.com | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:02
serv8.test.com | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:01
serv9.test.com | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:01
serv10.test.com | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:02
serv11.test.com | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:02
serv12.test.com | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:02
serv13.test.com | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:01
serv14.test.com | No   | 2013-02-21 | 10:25:01
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this type of query?

Comment: A self-exclusion join performs about the same as your solution for this small dataset: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7b834/6 But looking at the two explain plans the self-exclusion join has a lower cost so it may not hurt to try it out.

Comment: @bernie 2 seq scans + join rarery can be better than 1 seq scan and sort.

Comment: What happens if you create a composite index  (server, date, time)? EDIT: Sorry, I see that Igor already suggested this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try PosgreSQL specific `DISTINCT ON` clause like:

```
select distinct ON (server) server, fail, date, time
from querytimes
order by server, date desc, time desc;
```

If it is not fast enough try adding an index on `(server,date,time)`.

P.S. using reserved words like `date`, `time` for column names is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, that helps took about 3 seconds off. I will look into updating those column names.

Comment: Every min I am adding new data to this table for each server. Could I just do something like this,

    SELECT server, fail, date, time FROM querytimes ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 100; 

Then sort the results to be unique to "server"

That only takes about 2 seconds vs 19. If I know I have 44 servers I can get 100 most recent in case thing are being added while the query is happening.

Comment: select distinct ON (server) server, fail, date, time
from querytimes WHERE date > CURRENT_DATE - 1
order by server, date desc, time desc;

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - if all the records you want are going to be very recent, you could shrink the amount of records involved by limiting the search space to records less than x minutes old in the first place - possibly using a Common Table Expression to filter out a subset of records from the huge table, then do your real query on that smaller set of records.

```
With MostRecent as
( SELECT * from querytimes WHERE ( ...Postgres code to get latest... )
)
SELECT ...yourquery... FROM MostRecent
```

Plenty of date functions to play with at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Thanks, that what I ended up doing by adding,  WHERE date > CURRENT_DATE - 1

Comment: Did you want just one line per server? I could probably come up with a way to do that with a nested CTE :)

Comment: Yea I am looking to report on a webpage the last status of each server of it it failed or not. That why I wanted a quick response.

Comment: Ideally, if the database entries are under your control, you could just have another table LastQueries, just one row per server, updated and overwritten each time an entry is added to QueryEntries. You could then just select * from LastQueries.

Comment: Everything is under my control. That is a really good idea about just adding the new table. Never done a update before. Does this look to be the correct way to update.  UPDATE newtable SET fail = 'no', ms = '0.2123', time = "10:23:21", date = "02-21-2013 WHERE server = 'serv1.test.com' ?

Comment: Looks about right at a glance, must go, it's midnight here and I'm done in. Just remember to INSERT a record for each server first :)  More UPDATE info and examples here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-update.html  ... good luck

Comment: Got the collector script working with an UPDATE to the "recent_queries" table.

cur.execute("UPDATE recent_queries SET server = (%s) , ms = (%s), fail = (%s),  date = (%s), time = (%s) WHERE server = (%s) ", [serv, ms, fail, date, time, serv])